# How to change in app currency from Dollar to Indian Rupees in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using in app billing for users to purchase couple items. This app is geared towards Indian audience. I select India in market as target country and go to in app products and set up the amount as 50 cents. 
My question is when users in India open this in google checkout they see currency in $ as $.50 
How can i change this to Indian Rupees? Or if there is any option to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

The supported currencies are listed here:
http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138412

Unfortunately, INR is not one of the supported currencies.